# PSCP command using a batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, amazon-ec2, pscp

I need to transfer the latest file in a folder to aws server using  a simple batch script.
I am getting a date-stamped filename so ideally the largest file name should be the latest

The code used is as follows

```
@echo off
SET longfile =''

for %%a  in (c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\batch\*) do (


if %%a GTR %longfile%

%longfile% = %%a

)

pscp -i  c:\putty\pass.ppk %longfile% ubuntu@ec2-XXX-us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/
```

The above script does not work as the pscp command returns the error `file not found`.

Comment: Largest file is the latest? how about created file? a new file will be the latest.

Comment: So the main problem here is that `pscp` is not found? Sounds like you need to add it's directory to your PATH environment variable, or use the full path to the exe e.g. `C:\putty\pscp.exe -i ...`

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN 'dir "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\batch" /b /a-d-h /t:c /od') do set "latest=%%i"
echo Latest file is: %latest%
```